# Can't Maintain Network Transfer Speeds

Tags: windows-7, networking, ip-camera

I have a real head scratcher here. Has anyone ever encountered a situation in which a network can maintain a certain amount of data transfer over a short period, before dropping off suddenly? Restarting the program responsible for the data transfer eliminates the problem, temporarily.

I'm working with a small IP camera network - 3 installations, a total of 20 cameras running over CAT6 and POE into switches. Each installation is linked to the monitoring center via Ubiquiti Nanostations, ptp links. All cameras are monitored via a workstation running Blue Iris.

Recently we've been having some issues with low framerate - 1, 2 FPS. I noticed that if I restart Blue Iris, the frame rates increase, with a corresponding increase in network transfer (max is approx. 5500kB/s total). Strangely, after about 8 minutes, the speed drops 10-fold to ~500kB/s, and won't recover unless I restart the monitoring program. As soon as I restart, it works great. For another 8 minutes.

I've switched monitoring workstations, the PC isn't the bottleneck. I don't think that anything is overheating - Spot checking the switches doesn't reveal anything burning hot, and I imagine if it was a heat issue, the speed wouldn't recover with no time delay (ie. restarting the program immediately fixes the issue).

Thanks

Comment: I've had some FPS limiting issues when I upgraded to Blue Iris 4 for some reason last July. Reverting back to Blue Iris 3 fixed those issues for me. I'm sure you've already figured something out, just my 2¢

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend updating all firmwares and applications involved to the latest version. Also check your memory and hard-disk usage. Maybe some buffer fills up und therefore transmission speed slows down.

Comment: Everything is up to date AFAIK. I do have some more information, however: I segregated the camera network from the rest of the LAN, and the problem disappeared. I've got an inching feeling that it has something to do with the Win. 2008 box acting as a DHCP and DNS server. I'm still curious to know what the issue is, but unfortunately I'm working with a production environment, so I'm limited in what I can mess with.